# represent an integer using binary in java language

Tags: java, implementation, bit-manipulation

Here is the problem:

You're given 2 32-bit numbers, N & M, and two bit positions, i & j. write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M (e.g. M becomes a substring of N at locating at i
and starting at j)

For example:
  input: 
  int N = 10000000000, M = 10101, i = 2, j = 6;
  output:
    int N = 10001010100

My solution:

```
step 1: compose one mask to clear sets from i to j in N 
 mask=   ( ( ( ((1<<(31-j))-1) << (j-i+1) ) + 1 ) << i  ) - 1 
 for the example, we have 
       mask= 11...10000011
step 2: 
      (N & mask) | (M<<i)
```

Question:
    what is the convenient data type to implement the algorithm? for example
   we have int n = 0x100000 in C, so that we can apply bitwise operators on n.
   in Java, we have BitSet class, it has clear, set method, but doesnt support 
   left/right shift operator; if we use int, it supports left/right shift, but 
   doesnt have binary representation (I am not talking about binary string representation)
   what is the best way to implement this?

Code in java (after reading all comments):

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("10000000000",2);
int x = Integer.parseInt("10101",2);
int i = 2, j = 6;
public static int F(int x, int y, int i, int j){
int mask = (-1<<(j+1)) | (-1>>>(32-i));
return (mask & x ) | (y<<i);   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _"if we use int... but doesnt have binary representation?"_ You can absolutely apply `&` and `|` to ints in Java. Are you talking about writing an `int` literal in binary?

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about define an int literal in binary which is similar to this statement in C: int N = 0x101010;

Comment: No binary literals in Java. You've got decimal, octal and hexadecimal. But you could use `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` with a radix of 2 to start from a String representation. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the bit-wise operators `|`, `&`, `^` and `~` and the hex literal (`0x1010`) are all available in java

32 bit numbers are `int`s if that constraint remains `int` will be a valid data type

btw

```
mask = (-1<<j)|(-1>>>(32-i));
```

is a slightly clearer construction of the mask

Comment: In Java 7 there even is a binary literal: `0b1010`, which might come handy here.

Comment: the mask is very nice except that: want to clear the bits between i and j, which is j-i+1 bits. so need  -1 << (j+1) | -1 >>> (32-i)

Answer (score 0):

Java's `int` has all the operations you need. I did not totally understand your question (too tired now), so I'll not give you a complete answer, just some hints. (I'll revise it later, if needed.)

- Here are `j` ones in a row:  `(1 << j)-1`.
- Here are `j` ones in a row, followed by `i` zeros: `((1 << j) - 1) << i`.
- Here is a bitmask which masks out `j` positions in the middle of x: `x & ~(((1 << j) - 1) << i)`.

Try these with `Integer.toBinaryString()` to see the results. (They might also give strange results for negative or too big values.)

Comment: in this question, we need (j-i+1) positions in the middle of x

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how Java works. All values are represented as 'a series of bits' under the hood, ints and longs are included in that.

Based on your question, a rough solution is:

```
public static int applyBits(int N, int M, int i, int j) {
  M = M << i; // Will truncate left-most bits if too big

  // Assuming j > i
  for(int loopVar = i; loopVar < j; loopVar++) {
    int bitToApply = 1 << loopVar;
    // Set the bit in N to 0
    N = N & ~bitToApply;
    // Apply the bit if M has it set.
    N = (M & bitToApply) | N;
  }

  return N;
}
```

My assumptions are:

- `i` is the right-most (least-significant) bit that is being set in `N`.
- `M`'s right-most bit maps to `N`'s `i`th bit from the right.
- That premature optimization is the root of all evil - this is O(j-i). If you used a complicated mask like you did in the question you can do it in O(1), but it won't be as readable, and readable code is 97% of the time more important than efficient code.